# mongoose find then return subdocument with criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have the following data

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cdcb640e6d43d2c91e432aa"),
    "userID" : "quqrgfbf43adadonadb",
    "taggedProducts" : [ 
        {
            "isChecked" : true,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cdcb640e6d43d2c91e432ab"),
            "catalogSKU" : "MYLOAD 10",
            "createdBy" : "string",
            "modifiedBy" : "string",
            "remarks" : "string",
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-05-16T01:00:48.852Z"),
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-05-16T01:00:48.852Z")
        }, 
        {
            "isChecked" : false,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cdcb675e6d43d2c91e432ac"),
            "catalogSKU" : "MYLOAD 11",
            "createdBy" : "string",
            "modifiedBy" : "string",
            "remarks" : "string",
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-05-16T01:01:41.450Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-05-16T01:01:41.450Z")
        }, 
        {
            "isChecked" : true,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cdcd76b61d09c0cdd6fafdd"),
            "catalogSKU" : "MYLOAD 12",
            "createdBy" : "string",
            "modifiedBy" : "string",
            "remarks" : "string",
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-05-16T03:22:19.525Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-05-16T03:22:19.525Z")
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

GOAL: need to find the document using the userID then return all `"taggedProducts"` with `isChecked: true`

I tried many posts regarding this but there isnt code using `.find` first. the suggestion was to use `.aggregate`

I also tried using `$elemMatch` but it only returns the first sub-document that matches the criteria.

Can anyone suggest what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use [$elemMatch (projection)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/index.html) in this case since it only returns **first** matching element. Therefore you need [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) as a part of aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { userID: "quqrgfbf43adadonadb" }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            taggedProducts: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$taggedProducts",
                    cond: {
                        $eq: [ "$$this.isChecked", true ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/C3yI6uiyWUM)